# Android which intent flag required for start activity after android device home button press

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Bluetooth  application I have used fragments.when i am  in a fragment i pressed home button of android device .After that activity in foreground I want to first open the fragment from its previous state.I have used this code but it not working

note-I want to start same activity from its previous state

```
activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager
            .getRunningAppProcesses();



    for (int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {

        if (!procInfos.get(i).processName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.example.democamera")) {


            Log.e("Service", "in service");

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent1);




        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
           intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
           intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
           getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```